# React does not include cookie in requests to rails backend

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, cookies, session-cookies

My favorite stock request from react does not include the sessoion in the request header. This I think is the problem. Here is the react request:

```js
const handleFavorite = (stockId) => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/favorite_stock/${stockId}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      credentials: 'include',
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Failed to favorite stock');
        }
        setFavoriteMessage('Stock favorited!');
        setErrorMessage('');
  
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        setErrorMessage('');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        setErrorMessage('Failed to favorite stock. Please try again.');
      });
  };
```

I have added credentials include to all fetch requests
when a user logs in the server responds with a cookie value
my browser accepts all cookies

Comment: Show how you know that your "request from react does not include the sessoion in the request header"?